# A long time read body of request to http server with Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm using socket to create http socket server on Java android application.
Send and Get headers from client and server I'm getting fast. But get when trying read http body it takes a long time... why ?

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        runProxy();
                    }catch (Throwable t){

                    }
                };
        }).start();
    }

    private void runProxy() throws Throwable{
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.err.println("Client accepted");
                new Thread(new TestProxy(s)).start();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){

        }

    }
```

TestProxy.class

```
public class TestProxy implements Runnable{

    private Socket s, c;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;

    ArrayList<String> requestList;
    ArrayList<String> responseList;

    private BufferedReader br;

    public TestProxy(Socket s) throws Throwable{
        this.s = s;
        this.is = s.getInputStream();
        this.os = s.getOutputStream();

        this.requestList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.responseList = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.run();
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            this.readRequest();
            this.forwardRequest();
            this.forwardResponse(); //<--- this is trouble ??!
        }catch (Throwable e){

        }finally {
            /*try {
                s.close();
                c.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {}*/
        }
    }

    private void readRequest() throws Throwable{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        //int lengthBody = 0;
        while(true) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            requestList.add(s + "\r\n");
            /*if (s.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) { // get the
                // content-length
                int index = s.indexOf(':') + 1;
                String len = s.substring(index).trim();
                lengthBody = Integer.parseInt(len);
            }*/
            if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        is.close();

    }

    private void forwardRequest(){
        String firstSectionInProtocol = requestList.get(0); //GET http://example.com/?d=d HTTP/1.1
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\s+(\\S+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(firstSectionInProtocol);
        if(m.find()) {
            String URI = m.group(1); //http://example.com/?d=d
            try {
                URL aURL = new URL(URI);
                try {
                    c = new Socket(aURL.getHost(), 80);
                    final OutputStream outToServer = c.getOutputStream();

                    String firstSection = "GET "+aURL.getFile()+" HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                    outToServer.write(firstSection.getBytes());
                    System.out.println(firstSection);
                    for(int i = 1; i < requestList.size(); i++){
                        outToServer.write(requestList.get(i).getBytes());
                        System.out.println(requestList.get(i));
                    }
                    outToServer.flush();
                }catch (IOException e) {

                }

            }catch (MalformedURLException e){ }
        }
    }

    private void forwardResponse() throws Throwable{
        final InputStream inFromServer = c.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFromServer));
        int lengthBody = 0;
        while(true) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println( s + "\r\n" );
            if (s.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) { // get the
                // content-length
                int index = s.indexOf(':') + 1;
                String len = s.substring(index).trim();
                lengthBody = Integer.parseInt(len);
            }
            if(s.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        //
        // Processing long time
        //
        if (lengthBody > 0) {
            int read;
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            while ((read = br.read()) != -1) {
                body.append((char) read);
                if (body.length() >= lengthBody)
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println(body.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

in the method forwardResponse(); i trying get a body response.

Comment: You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP, especially the parts about content-length and chunked transfers.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(true) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println( s + "\r\n" );
            /*if (s.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) { // get the
                // content-length
                int index = s.indexOf(':') + 1;
                String len = s.substring(index).trim();
                lengthBody = Integer.parseInt(len);
            }*/
            if(s == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The null check is in the wrong place. This will throw NPE at end of stream.